# How to update mail chimp subscriber data

Tags: php, email, mailchimp

I am using mail chimp for news letter subscription.I am add a new field 'verified' for news letter verification , means if we click "Yes Keep sending emails" it will update the verified field by 1.

The field in mail chimp like...
[image: Mailchimp field]

If we subscribe a news letter , we got an email like...

[image: Email notification]

if we click ***"Yes Keep sending emails"*** it should update the verified field by 1.

But I don't know how it's possible.I am search in google ,but I don't get a clear idea about it.Any one please help me

Comment: At time of calling the function `listSubscribe()` there is an option of `double_optin` make it true hope will work for you. And you no need to create custom link `Yes, Keep Sending Me mails` it will generate automatic. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mailchimp API then you need to set update_existing flag **true** . Here is the listSubscribe method.

```
 listSubscribe(string apikey, string id, string email_address, array merge_vars, string email_type, bool double_optin, bool update_existing, bool replace_interests, bool send_welcome)
```

By setting update_existing flag true it keeps the records update.